# Are there any circumstances in which an IO function can never fail?

Tags: c, function, file, error-handling, io

Most IO functions (`fopen`, `fread`, etc) can fail if the system encounters an error, or if a passed argument is invalid (`fseek` to some value other than `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, or `SEEK_END`), but they can also fail for reasons beyond the programmers control. Checking for success is tedious and *might* sometimes unnecessary. Are there any circumstances in which a function *will not* fail even if it could fail in certain circumstances? Such as `fclose`ing a file opened in read only mode, and the file pointer was freshly returned by `fopen`? When do I not have to worry about an IO function failing? Are these such circumstances?

- File was opened in READ mode
- File pointer was returned by `fopen` and nullchecked
- Read operations

What other circumstances?

I do not see why `fclose` would fail on a file opened in READ mode, because there is not going to be any buffers written to the file, all that needs to happen is freeing up memory, and `free` cannot fail so neither should `fclose`, **is this assumption correct**?

Also should I avoid `rewind` because it cannot indicate error?

Comment: No. All IO functions can fail. Always check the result. Unfortunately, 80% of every sane program is error checking and exceptions handling. Imagine that file is remote and the connection fails. You may be left with open handle.

Comment: You could just read the man page. fclose fails if the FD is bad.

Comment: @stark What would cause FD to be bad if it was successfully returned by `fopen`

Comment: Apart from `EBADF`, from the man page: _"The fclose() function may also fail and set errno for any of the errors specified for the routines close(2), write(2), or fflush(3)."_ (Note however that `write` and `close` are POSIX-specific functions, the situation may be different in some cases).

Comment: The fd value was accidentally overwritten elsewhere in your program, but you never find out because you don't check the return.

Comment: @stark What if it is a local variable and there is no way for any other parts of the program can touch it?

Comment: @user16156443 No amount of ruling out situations that people can think of can produce a guarantee because there can always be another situation that nobody was able to think of. You only have a guarantee if the relevant specification states one.

Comment: The close call may fail to update the access time in the inode.  Another thread could have inherited the file descriptor and re-opened it for write.  It could be a network mount, say CIFS, and the server has been hit by a stray bowling ball.  But feel free to be sloppy if you want.  Lots of people don't check the return from close.

Comment: @stark Ok but what should I do then if fclose fails?

Comment: Log an error and take appropriate action.

Comment: @stark What would appropriate action be?

Comment: Switch to the backup computer.  Scram the reactor. Safely park the self-driving car.  Let slip the dogs of war.

Comment: Note that [`rewind()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) returns no value; you have to go through multiple steps to know whether it failed.  The macOS manual says: _Since `rewind()` does not return a value, an application wishing to detect errors should clear `errno`, then call `rewind()`, and if `errno` is non-zero, assume an error has occurred._. Reading the manual is an important part of using C functions.

Comment: For a file opened for reading, the corresponding close operation is very unlikely to fail.  But "very unlikely" is not "guaranteed not to".  I agree with the other commentators.  Just always check.  You will spend more time -- *much* more time -- trying to convince yourselves which calls "can't" fail, and tracking down obscure bugs when perhaps one of them does, than you will spend just checking them all, anyway.

Comment: @stark Love the ["Let slip the dogs of war"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dogs_of_war_(phrase)).

Comment: user16156443: "I do not see why fclose would fail on a file opened in READ mode" --> in 10 years from now, there may be a very common reason.  No need to code for the present only.